# Need help with clothing my character mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm not entirely sure how specific I can be, but i need help with adding cloths to my character. Every tutorial I've seen so far are all tight fit clothing so it just looks like everyone is wearing under armor. I want to learn how to make it a bit more baggy, especially the pants. Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets see if this helps.

[image]

1. Select all the faces of the mesh your want to make clothes for.
   I did face select, then i highlighted all the faces. (Photo above)

[image]

2. Duplicate that mesh by hitting 'Shift + D', then press 'enter'. After this you want to scale the mesh by going to your tools manu and hitting the 'scale', 'shrink/fatten', or 'push/pull' tab. (photo above and below)

[image]

3. To make the mesh "baggy" or thicker you can add a modifier like 'solidify'. (photo below)

[image]

4. change the 'thickness' value to get the desired results. (photo below)
   [image]
5. these were my results.(photo below)
   [image]
6. Thats it! now just shape your clothes to the desired shape and/or add a subdivision surface modifier to make it smoother. Then if you want you can sculpt the clothing, but thats all up to you.

Comment: THANK YOU!! THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!
you have no idea how much this has helped me. Greatly appreciated

Comment: your very welcome, have fun!!!